# Progress bar for copy disappears

Tags: 16.04, nautilus, copy

When I make long copy operations (which usually is to USB-flash memories), the progress window often disappears completely if I put it out of focus. I have tried some hints using alt/tab and `wmctrl`, but I can't get the progress window back.

I can see a very small grey bar on top of the corresponding launcher icon. But there is no way to terminate the copy operation or to see details.

Can I bring the copy progress window back somehow?

I use v 16.04 default setup. (I hope it is correct to use the Nautilus tag.)

Comment: You wont like 16.10 ;)

Answer (score 4):

This is not the most intuitive method but you can right click on the nautilus icon and then click on the "Show Copy Dialog" option.

Comment: This doesn't (always) work. There's a long-standing bug where it vanishes forever (well, until you log out and back in again).

Comment: Confirming, neither works for me. Can't uh-hide the progress window.